# Can I set DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH with maven-surefire-plugin?

Tags: macos, maven

In a Java project, I depend on a third-party native library that in turn loads dependency dylibs via `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. I've successfully run tests via Tycho's surefire plugin by setting this with the `environmentVariables` property of the plugin config, but a similar setup in a non-OSGi project leaves the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable unset.

Here's a snippet of my functioning Tycho configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.25.0</version>

    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.library.path="${dylib-program}"</argLine>
        <environmentVariables>
            <DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>${dylib-program}</DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>
        </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

With that, the tests run correctly, and outputting `System.getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH")` shows the set path.

Here's the equivalent snippet from my non-Tycho config:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.library.path="${dylib-program}"</argLine>
        <environmentVariables>
            <DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>${dylib-program}</DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH>
            <OtherVar>bar</OtherVar>
        </environmentVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run this, however, the dependency library doesn't load properly and `System.getenv("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH")` returns `null`. `System.getenv("OtherVar")`, however, returns `"bar"`, so setting environment variables generally seems to work. That makes me suspect that there's something peculiar about `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (and the same happened with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but not `PATH`).

The behavior is the same when run in Eclipse (either as-is or with the path also set in the Run Configuration environment) and via the command line (again either as-is or with the environment variable explicitly exported before the run). The Tycho and non-Tycho projects are run on the same machine, with the same tools (other than the test plugins). I'm using macOS 10.12.3, Java 1.8.0_111, and Maven 3.3.9.

Is there a general limitation about setting this property, at least on a Mac, or is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: Have you tried running maven with -DDYLD_LIBRARY_PATH =myValue ?

Comment: Good idea, but sadly that doesn't seem to have an effect. Along similar lines, I also tried setting it through `systemPropertyVariables`, with the same null result.

Comment: So I've tried on my Linux with your configuration and it worked (with LD_LIBRARY_PATH), so maybe I did not understand it fully. In your pom, am I right to assume that you set the value of the `${dylib-program}` variable? Am I right also to assume you want the environment variable to get its value during the testing phase?

Comment: Yes on both counts: I set the dylib-program property originally in my local .m2/settings.xml, and then also in the project pom for testing, and I do want it to exist as an environment variable during testing. I see the same as you do on Linux: it works without issue. It seems like it's something peculiar on the Mac that the Tycho surefire plugin somehow sidesteps.

Comment: I think that this article could give an explanation on the difference observed: http://4js.com/online_documentation/fjs-fgl-manual-html/c_fgl_JavaBridge_008.html   "On Mac OS X, the usage of DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is strongly discouraged, especially since OS X 10.11 this environment variable is no longer exported in sub processes."

Comment: Good call - it could be that Tycho by necessity uses an alternate method to spawn the test runtime and so doesn't run afoul of macOS's stripping of the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. Unfortunately, I don't have a lot of control over the need for the variable (it's an IBM library, and not liable to change any time soon), but this gives me a good route to investigate further - thanks!

Comment: Not being a Mac user myself I hope not to be out of topic too much, because from what I understand you can either deactivate the "System Integrity Protection" (no idea what are the consequences though...), or use the default path for your library. (/usr/local/lib apparently). Then on the testing phase, you could use maven to copy this IBM library there, and clean it afterwards.